# Which R to use to indicate the real numbers?

Tags: notation, real-numbers

In general, when people are talking about set of real numbers, they usually use one of the following notations:

> $$\tag{1} x \in R.$$
>   $$\tag{2} x \in \textbf{R}.$$
>   $$\tag{3} x \in \mathbb{R}.$$
>   $$\tag{4} x \in \Re.$$

I understand that it might be convient to use one notation over the other (e.g. when the letter $R$ assigned a different meaning already, like a region of integration).

However I am curious whether there is an actual distinction between the notation, like a historical reason, or is it just preference which notation to use?

The last one seems to be used quite often as wel..

Comment: No (4) used for real part of a complex number.

Comment: In Operations Research (4) is used a lot to specify the real numbers.

Comment: @Glasses, one would more conventionally use `\Re` instead of `\mathfrak R` tho.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician thanks didn't know that shortcut :) !

Comment: Note that the third of these is by far the easiest to draw by hand (e.g. on a blackboard or paper), if one only double-bars the leftmost vertical line.

Comment: There is no right choice. It's about context, and as long as the reader is aware of the meaning of the symbol it's fine. In set theory you can find $\Bbb R$ used for denoting a forcing poset quite often.

Comment: Several related questions have been posted on this site:
[Blackboard bold, Bold, Fraktur, and Reserved Variable](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1072685),
[Why do mathematicians use this symbol $\mathbb R$ to represent the real numbers?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/217047)
[Who invented or used very first the double lined symbols $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{N}$ etc](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/873521)
and even on meta [Blackboard bold](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2528).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Nr. (1)** usually used for a region in analysis, and is a ring in algebra also,

**Nr. (2)** not conventional in new mathematical books for reals. Some people use *Bold* characters for vectors, like **A, B, ...**

**Nr. (3)** is the best character, preferred by many mathematicians. This character specific number sets like $\mathbb{R}$ for *real numbers*, $\mathbb{C}$ for *complex numbers*, $\mathbb{Q}$ for *rationals*, $\mathbb{Z}$ for *integers*, $\mathbb{N}$ for *natural numbers*, and so on. It is the best character for this purpose.

**Nr. (4)** designed for real part of a complex number in computer editors, but mathematicians don't used it vastly. They used bold $Re$ (**Re**) instead of it.

Answer (score 7):

it is $$\mathbb{R}$$ the right sign

Comment: goodlike answer (+1)!

Answer (score 3):

I prefer $\mathbf{R}$ in print, leaving $\mathbb{R}$ for writing on paper or blackboard.

It's an aesthetic choice,
   also made by Serre and Knuth for instance:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackboard_bold

See a discussion at

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sage-devel/aM3wW0AwMoY/KwNSMcPxeLcJ

Comment: In StackExchange one uses $\Bbb R$, as Dr. Sonnhard Graubner indicates   (a competitive sick has put him a downvote).

Comment: I use $\Bbb R$ here too, to avoid noise.